# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at youtubedl.js:4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going through a tutorial and it's from 2 years ago so I am assuming perhaps YouTube has changed up things. I am trying to get the URL  programmatically. I'm following the tutorial to a tee, but I seem to be getting this error and I'm not sure why.

update: Should this be put as a code snippet?

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name" : "Simple Youtube Downloader", 
    "description" : "Download youtube videos simpler than before. ",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "author" : "Nick Germaine",
    "web_accessible_resources" : ["src/youtubedl.js"],
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "matches" : ["https://www.youtube.com/watch*"],
            "js" : ["src/loader.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**loader.js**

```
s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("src/youtubedl.js");

s.onload = function(){
    this.remove();
}

document.head.appendChild(s);
```

**youtubedl.js**

```
var videoUrls = window.ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(",");
    
console.log("our extension has loaded");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `youtubedl.js` file, try replacing the first line with this:

`var videoUrls = window.ytplayer.config.args.loaderUrl`,

because entering `window.ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(",");` into the console shows as undefined.

Comment: thanks, that worked! How come my way wasn't working?

Comment: I guess that, like you said, YouTube changed its behind the scenes since the tutorial was made. The `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` property no longer exists. The Chrome console actually suggested the `loaderUrl` property instead of `url` when I was testing this line.